# ¿como deshabilitar radiobutton con checkbox?

Tags: jsp, checkbox, radiobutton

Cuando selecciono un checkbox se bloquea los radio button y el valor es almacenado en la base de datos, **pero al actualizar la pagina el checkbox me retorna con checked pero el radiobuton no esta deshabilitado**, tanto el radio button como el checkbox están en el mismo campo de la bd

```js
 $('#ninguno_quiro').click(function() {
// Si esta seleccionado (si la propiedad checked es igual a true)
if ($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).is(':selected')  ) {
$('.radioquiru').attr('checked', false).attr('disabled', true);
$('.listado').attr('checked', true);
$("input[class=textoquiru]").attr('disabled',true);
} else {
$('.listado').attr('checked', false);
$('.radioquiru').attr('disabled', false);
}
});

$("input[id=ninguno_quiro][value='<%=ninguno_quiro%>']").prop("checked",true);
$("input[id=consulta_asa_e][value='<%=consulta_asa_e%>']").prop("checked",true);
$("input[name=consulta_asa_e][value='<%=consulta_asa_e%>']").prop("checked",true);
 $("input[name=ayuno_e][value='<%=ayuno_e%>']").prop("checked",true);
```

```html
<td class="Subtitulo">SI</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">NO</td>
<td class="Subtitulo">NA.</td>
<td ><label ><input  type="checkbox" id="ninguno" name="ninguno" value="3"></label></td>
 <td class="Subtitulo">ACTIVIDAD</td>
<tr>
<td><label >Consulta (ASA)</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio1"  name="consulta_asa_e" class="radioquiru"></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio2" name="consulta_asa_e" class="radioquiru" /></td>
 <td><label ><input  type="checkbox" value="3" id="consulta_asa_e"  class="listado"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="conf_nom_proc"> 6 a 8 horas</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" id="miradio3" name="ayuno_e"  class="radioquiru"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" id="miradio4" name="ayuno_e" class="radioquiru"/></td>
 <td><label for="chk3"><input type="checkbox" value="3" id="ayuno_e" class="listado"/></label></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: no soy experto ni nada por el estilo, ni mucho menos conozco muy bien JS. Por lo que veo en tu código, es que antes deberías de realizar una consulta a la base de datos y te jale el estado de los valores, tanto de tu checkbox como de tu radiobutton, para que así se pueda saber que valores, debería de tener en base a lo que hayas guardado anteriormente, ya después sería el código que te cambia los valores y por último insertar esos nuevos valores a la base de datos. Espero que te sea de ayuda lo que te comento. Saludos.

Comment: Si coloque la consulta en el codigo completo, no lo puse aqui porque creo que se sobreentiende